# How do I ensure a code is called BEFORE anything else in Expo/React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want to execute the SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync before any other code.

I have placed it before any other code including with the hope it is called before any other functional components but after the imports

```
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
... other imports ...

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync().catch(() => {
  /* reloading the app might trigger some race conditions, ignore them */
});

...

export default function App() {
...
}
```

However, I am not sure if there is anything in the `import`s that is causing my splash screen from disappearing without `SplashScreen.hideAsync().catch(() => {});`

Could I just use `require` instead of `import` to ensure the order of execution?

Comment: Where have you placed the code? Inside `useEffect` in App()?

Comment: before the root `export default function App`

Comment: I am suspecting there may be some import which I can't seem to find that does the hide.  Since this is legacy code.